# Initializing private variables inside a constructor

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I have been looking at this code for a comparator. My question is there a specific benefit of initializing the two private variables inside the constructor(Done here in the default constructor). I know the second constructor can be used to create an instance with supplied values. What difference would it make if I do

```
private String sortBy = COLUMN_LAST_NAME;
private boolean ascending = true;
```

I apologize if its a real simple and generic question.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<StudentList>
{   private String sortBy;
private boolean ascending;

public CustomComparator()
{
    sortBy = COLUMN_LAST_NAME;
    ascending = true;
}

public CustomComparator(String sortBy, boolean ascending)
{
    this.sortBy = sortBy;
    this.ascending = ascending;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it matters if you care about object immutability (and you should :-)). If both of your fields are `final`, you must initialize them like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {
    private final String sortBy;
    private final boolean ascending;

    public CustomComparator() {
        sortBy = COLUMN_LAST_NAME;
        ascending = true;
    }

    public CustomComparator(String sortBy, boolean ascending) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }
}
```

Or even better:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {
    private final String sortBy;
    private final boolean ascending;

    public CustomComparator() {
        this(COLUMN_LAST_NAME, true);
    }

    public CustomComparator(String sortBy, boolean ascending) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, if I do private final boolean ascending = true; outside the constructor, How would that affect object immutability?

Comment: @t0mcat To the point that the parametric constructor cannot be used at all.

Comment: @t0mcat: Because once assigned `final` value cannot be changed in constructor or any other place (exactly once semantic)

Comment: final fields can be assigned only one time. If you assign the value outside the constructor then you cannot assign any new value. Think on final fields like photos, you cannot asign any new value

Answer (score 6):

The best practice i've seen preached everywhere is have one constructor that takes all parameters, even if it means it has to be private, and then just call it from other constructors using `this(..,..,...)` while supplying appropriate values.

This will make you reuse as much code as possible and future fixes go to one place and one place only - no need to make double maintenance of code.

Your example would look like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<StudentList> {
    private String sortBy;
    private boolean ascending;

    public CustomComparator()
    {
        this(COLUMN_LAST_NAME, true);
    }

    public CustomComparator(String sortBy, boolean ascending)
    {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }
}
```

Initialization is generally accepted to be in the constructor as to distinguish easier between static initialization of static members and per-instance init of instance variables. There is no performance difference.

Comment: If you don't want to clutter your constructors with initialisation of your private variables, e.g. because they are independent of outside code (assume sortBy is already initialized to the same value independent of the used constructor) and they can't be assigned in a short one liner you could use initializer blocks.

Answer (score 1):

it's all about what you need, both constructor are good choices, obviuosly if you want to initialize the fields is the best choice but think if you use this class like an Entity on Hibernate or like a bean on Spring framework, if you dont write the empty constructor nothing will run fine...

if you think in DTO patterns, declaring inmutable fields like @Tomasz Nurkiewicz says then the parametrized constructor is the only choice....

but like i say before, it depends on requeriments...

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any difference and I prefer initializing in the variable declaration.

Comment: Hi carlosZ, I am a newbie so even these sort of simple declarations makes me wonder if I am missing something :-)